# Is it possible to create EMR cluster with Auto scaling using Data pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline, data-pipeline

I am new to AWS. I have created a EMR cluster using Auto scaling policy through AWS console. I have also created a data pipeline which can use this cluster to perform the activities.

I am also able to create EMR cluster dynamically through data pipeline. But while doing it I am not able to assign Auto scaling Rule to the EMR cluster . Is there a way to configure auto scaling role and other required configurations to EMR cluster through data pipeline

Answer (score 0):

It is **not possible** to have AWS Data Pipeline launch an Amazon EMR cluster with Auto Scaling.

Nor is really necessary.

**AWS Data Pipeline** launches an Amazon EMR cluster to perform some work, such as transforming data or moving data between systems. Once such a task is complete, the **cluster is terminated**. This is known as a *transient* cluster.

This is a very different use-case to a **long-running Amazon EMR cluster** that accepts ad-hoc jobs throughout the day and can take advantage of Auto Scaling to add/remove capacity based upon demand.

Thus, there really isn't a need to add Auto Scaling to an EMR cluster launched by Data Pipeline. Instead, **specify the capacity up-front** and it will be used for the duration of the job.

Comment: Agreed. But assume I am doing transformation on some data on weekly basis and the data size keeps changing every week. So I am not sure on how many nodes are required in my cluster for better performance. If I have Auto scaling, then based on number of params I can try to auto scale my cluster.